# How to fix concurrent merge sort in go

Tags: go, concurrency, mergesort

I am trying to learn go lang and facing problems in implementing merge sort concurrently. It is not sorting the array properly

I have tried finding any race conditions and also tried printing at various stages. But couldn't seem to figure out the issue. Any tool to analyze and point out such issues.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func merge(a []int, ch chan int) {
    //     defer close(ch)
    if len(a) == 0 {
        close(ch)
        return
    }

    if len(a) == 1 {
        ch <- a[0]
        close(ch)
        return
    }

    mid := len(a) / 2

    ch1 := make(chan int)
    go merge(a[:mid], ch1)

    ch2 := make(chan int)
    go merge(a[mid:], ch2)

    v1, ok1 := <-ch1
    v2, ok2 := <-ch2
    var t []int
    for ok1 == true && ok2 == true {
        if v1 < v2 {
            ch <- v1
            t = append(t, v1)
            v1, ok1 = <-ch1
        } else {
            ch <- v2
            t = append(t, v2)
            v2, ok2 = <-ch2
        }
    }
    close(ch)
}

func Merge(a []int) (sortedA []int) {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go merge(a, ch)

    for v := range ch {
        sortedA = append(sortedA, v)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    arr := []int{3, 34, 23, 65, 34, 7, -1, 0, -23}
    start := time.Now()
    b := Merge(arr)
    fmt.Printf("Time taken to sort: %v, sorted: %v", time.Since(start), b)
}
```

I expected the output to be `[-23 -1 0 3 7 23 34 34 65]` but the actual output is only `-23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your merge phase is broken: You have to send on `ch` all values from `ch1` and `ch2` but your code stops once *any* of `ch1` *or* `ch2` is drained. Once you drained e.g. `ch2` you have to send everything from `ch1` to `c`.

Something along (make sure to clean up the conditions!)

```
for ok1 || ok2 {
    if (ok1 && ok2 && v1 < v2) || (ok1 && !ok2) {
        ch <- v1
        v1, ok1 = <-ch1
    } else if (ok1 && ok2 && v1 >= v2) || (!ok1 && ok2) {
        ch <- v2
        v2, ok2 = <-ch2
    }
}
```